# previous or original

Tags: discourse-context

(1) CONTEXT: I changed my plan.
Could I use my previous plan to indicate what the plan was before change?
Could I use my new/changed/current plan to indicate what the plan is after change?
If the two questions are OK, could I say "my new/changed/current plan is more suitable for company developing than my previous plan was"?

(2) CONTEXT: The caterpillar changed to a butterfly.
Could I use the previous caterpillar to indicate what the form of the animal was before change?
Could I use the current butterfly to indicate what the form of the animal is after change?
If the two questions are OK, could I say "the current caterpillar is more beautiful than the previous caterpillar was"?
If the two questions are not good, what is the differnce between the "plan" example and the "caterpillar" example?
Thank you!

Comment: Your second context looks "clumsy" to me, since there was only ever one caterpillar and one butterfly (so there can't be a "previous" caterpillar). But you could refer to *the **previous state** [of the one-and-only insect]*. And in the *first* context, I think most people would refer to their ***earlier*** or ***first** plan* unless they specifically wanted to imply that they'd had multiple versions of the plan before (and they're specifically referring to *the **immediately preceding** plan*). But not everyone would make that distinction, I'm sure.

Comment: Excuse me! Why is the first context acceptable, and the second one clumsy? In my understanding, after the caterpillar changed to a butterfly, the entity caterpillar is past and does not exist. As such, at the utterance, I can called the caterpillar as "previous caterpillar". Additionally, I changed my plan. In my understanding, after the plan change, the earlier plan is not used, and the new one is used. As such, I called the plan provided before as "the earlier plan". But you said the second is clumsy, I am confused the two difference.

Comment: *The/A previous X* usually implies the existence of *multiple* X's - invariably at least two, but more often at least three (if there was only one other before the "current" one, we'd more likely call that the ***first*** or ***original X***). There was only ever one caterpillar, which is why I don't like calling it the *previous caterpillar* (but I'd be happy to say the insect had previously been a caterpillar). Since there have been at least two plans, it's quite reasonable to call earlier versions of it *previous plans* (or *the previous / first / original  plan* if there were only two).

Comment: Thank you! But my current hair style and my previous hair style can't exist at the same time. For example, at the speaking time, my hair style has changed. So my previous hair style is past.